# How can I prevent wpf color properties from being overridden?

Tags: wpf, textbox, styles

I am creating a user control which contains a border, a text box, and additional controls.

All the controls are contained within the border.

How do i prevent general styles from affecting the text box's within my user control?

For example, I have a style in my resource file that makes the text box's in my app have rounded corners. 99% of the time this is what I want. How do I prevent the text box's in my user control from being affected by that style?

Comment: I may have figured it out. If i have a resource dictionary defined in my user control then it does appear that is used over any other resources used on a window.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> Typically, the search will begin by walking up the element tree
>   searching for an appropriate resource, then look in the application
>   resource collection and finally query the system. This gives
>   application developers a chance to redefine the style for any object
>   at the tree or application level before reaching the theme.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx

So essentially, the closer(from a LogicalTree point of view) to the actual point of use that the Style or property is defined, the greater its level of precedence.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i did figure that out basically after play with a few things.